# Read CSV as list - Python

Tags: python

so I have an output that is spitting out a bunch of floats in separate lines, such as:

0.0

0.0

1.4

0.0

2.3

You get the idea. I want to be able to convert all of these floats into a list so that I can use a maximum function to return only the max value (2.3 in this case). Is there a way to do that? I got this output by pulling it out of the csv if the condition before (the maximum temperature must be over 35) is met for the rainfall data is considered. Right now the print(rainfall) is currently printing the floats in the format above.

```
first_line = True
for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if first_line:
    first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    max_temp = float(values[2])
    rainfall = (values[3])
    if max_temp > 35:
      print(rainfall)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried to make a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can append to a list like this and then do max() accordingly

```
final_list = []

first_line = True
for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if first_line:
    first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    max_temp = float(values[2])
    rainfall = (values[3])
    if max_temp > 35:
      final_list.append(rainfall)

print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Acurrate title would be "Read CSV as list - Python". Anyway:

```py
import csv

#Open csv file as read-only
with open('climate_data_2017.csv', 'r') as myCSVData:
  #Pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
  csv_reader = csv.reader(myCSVFile) 
  #Pass reader object to list() to get a list of lists
  list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)

#Print results
print(str(list_of_rows))
print(str(max(list_of_rows)))
```